# Angular 10 The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

Tags: angular

I am learning **angular 10**. Below is my service where I am fetching data from inbuilt API

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getData() {
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

This API returns data as `array` of `objects` but when I try to assign this data in my `app.component.ts` to one `array` variable it says this data is `object`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'routing-demo';
  data=[]
  constructor(private user:UsersService) {

    this.user.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      this.data=data
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
}
```

I do tried below solutions as well

```
this.data.push(data);
```

But getting same error as

> "TS2696: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did
> you mean to use the 'any' type instead?   Type 'Object' is missing the
> following properties from type 'never[]': length, pop, push, concat,
> and 26 more."

Comment: What's the return type of `getData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the correct types ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gzwtpw?file=src/index.html)):

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

interface Data {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
    return this.http.get<Data[]>(url);
  }
}
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

interface Data {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'routing-demo';
  data: Data[] = [];

  constructor(private user: UsersService) {
    this.user.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      this.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

You data type is:

```
interface Data {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

and the response contains an array of it. You should create a file like `data.ts` with

```
export interface Data {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

and import it in your component and service.

Answer (score 4):

Just declare `data=[]` to `data: any = [];` and your issue will be resolved.

Also you can check my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dtqykb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Your solution is to disable the type checking system. That's not a solution. That's the worst you can do in this situation. You should set the correct types instead.

Comment: @ThomasSablik  return type of getData is object, whereas it should be array. Do you have any other solution for this problem?

Comment: @Radha Yes, set the actual type of your data in the request. It looks like you expect some kind of array: `this.http.get<TYPE[]>(url);`. Now the return type is `getData(): Observable<TYPE[]> {`. You should also set the type of `data: TYPE[] = []`. But since you didn't describe `TYPE` it's not possible to answer. More details are necessary to find a correct answer.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Can you please open this url - "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" it returns array of object so ideally return type of getData should be array but if I print its return type then it is object. So answer for your question "What's the return type of getData?" is "OBJECT"

Comment: @Radha No, return type is `{userId: number; id: number; title: string; completed: boolean}[]` but you have to set it everywhere in your code. Using `any` means losing IDE support and type checking. You should never use `any`.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasSablik given solution worked. Does that mean, everytime I use any external API then I need to define interface for its objects datatypes?

Comment: @Radha Yes, usually you have a folder named `models` or `data` only containing interfaces: e.g. https://angular-folder-structure.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/ You can use `any` in your small hobby projects but if you use it in a job interview in a larger company you can go home without the job.